# Round Corners in IE using ui-corner-all

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, jquery-ui

I was trying to get rounded corners in IE7 using jQuery's "ui-corner-all" class. This is how my page looks like.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#btnSearch').addClass("ui-corner-all");
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!--some code here-->
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
<!--some code here-->
</body>
</html>
```

But, I'm not able to get that effect of rounded corners. Am I doing something wrong here? I also tried including jQuery's smoothness.css file, but still nothing worked!

Comment: http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/achieving_rounded_corners_in_internet_explorer_for_jquery_ui_with_dd_roundi/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.ui-corner-all` is a CSS class in the [jQuery UI CSS framework](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming/API#Corner_Radius_helpers), it's not just available.  Even then...it doesn't work in IE < 9 :)

If you need to support IE < 9, you may want to look at the [jQuery Corner plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/).

[You can see what various IE versions support here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(VS.85).aspx#border).  The relevant part is it doesn't support **border-radius**.  This (along with the custom mozilla and webkit versions before the spec) is what the `.ui-corner-xxx` classes use to get CSS rounded corners.