# IE7+ Rounded Corners w/ jQueryUI

Tags: css, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-theme

I'm not really sure how to accomplish this with this [theme](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#ffDefault=Segoe+UI%2C+Arial%2C+sans-serif&fwDefault=bold&fsDefault=1.1em&cornerRadius=8px&bgColorHeader=817865&bgTextureHeader=12_gloss_wave.png&bgImgOpacityHeader=45&borderColorHeader=494437&fcHeader=ffffff&iconColorHeader=fadc7a&bgColorContent=feeebd&bgTextureContent=03_highlight_soft.png&bgImgOpacityContent=100&borderColorContent=8e846b&fcContent=383838&iconColorContent=d19405&bgColorDefault=fece2f&bgTextureDefault=12_gloss_wave.png&bgImgOpacityDefault=60&borderColorDefault=d19405&fcDefault=4c3000&iconColorDefault=3d3d3d&bgColorHover=ffdd57&bgTextureHover=12_gloss_wave.png&bgImgOpacityHover=70&borderColorHover=a45b13&fcHover=381f00&iconColorHover=bd7b00&bgColorActive=ffffff&bgTextureActive=05_inset_soft.png&bgImgOpacityActive=30&borderColorActive=655e4e&fcActive=0074c7&iconColorActive=eb990f&bgColorHighlight=fff9e5&bgTextureHighlight=12_gloss_wave.png&bgImgOpacityHighlight=90&borderColorHighlight=eeb420&fcHighlight=1f1f1f&iconColorHighlight=ed9f26&bgColorError=d34d17&bgTextureError=07_diagonals_medium.png&bgImgOpacityError=20&borderColorError=ffb73d&fcError=ffffff&iconColorError=ffe180&bgColorOverlay=5c5c5c&bgTextureOverlay=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityOverlay=50&opacityOverlay=80&bgColorShadow=cccccc&bgTextureShadow=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityShadow=30&opacityShadow=60&thicknessShadow=7px&offsetTopShadow=-7px&offsetLeftShadow=-7px&cornerRadiusShadow=8px).

The [Filament Group](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/achieving_rounded_corners_in_internet_explorer_for_jquery_ui_with_dd_roundi/) has shown some promise in this [demo](http://filamentgroup.com/examples/jquery-ui-themeroller-roundies/).  But not all that glimmers is gold, since the accordion and other plugins won't work correctly (it's a work in progress).

Related questions include: [Round Corners in IE using ui-corner-all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448564/round-corners-in-ie-using-ui-corner-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible IE7+ without other CSS/Image techniques

---

**Follow-up:**
If you did want to apply some hackery, there is a way to "easily" apply rounded corners in IE - that is, someone has done all the work and you just have to include a few files and change some CSS: http://css3pie.com/